# How to capture messages written to stderr by OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, stderr

In case of invalid parameters, `cv2.VideoWriter` writes stuff to stderr. here is a minimal example:

```py
import cv2

cv2.VideoWriter("foo.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v"), 90000, (240, 240))
```

Running like so

```sh
python3 video_verification/verification.py 2> err.txt
```

one can see the expected errors in `err.txt`:

```
[mpeg4 @ 0x13e4640] timebase 1/90000 not supported by MPEG 4 standard, the maximum admitted value for the timebase denominator is 65535
[ERROR:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-13uokl4r/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp (2705) open Could not open codec mpeg4, error: Unspecified error
[ERROR:0] global /tmp/pip-req-build-13uokl4r/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp (2722) open VIDEOIO/FFMPEG: Failed to initialize VideoWriter
```

However, I'm unable to capture this directly in Python. Here are my two (failing) attemps so far:

```py
import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout, redirect_stderr

import cv2

f_out = io.StringIO()
f_err = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f_out):
    with redirect_stderr(f_err):
        fps = 90000
        writer = cv2.VideoWriter(
            "foo.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v"),
            fps, (240, 240)
        )

print(f"stdout: {f_out.getvalue()}")
print(f"stderr: {f_err.getvalue()}")
```

```py
import io
import sys

import cv2


def flush():
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stderr.flush()


flush()

original_stdout = sys.stdout
original_stderr = sys.stderr

captured_stdout = io.StringIO()
captured_stderr = io.StringIO()

sys.stdout = captured_stdout
sys.stderr = captured_stderr

flush()

cv2.VideoWriter("foo.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v"), 90000, (240, 240))

flush()

sys.stdout = original_stdout
sys.stderr = original_stderr

print(f"stdout: {captured_stdout.getvalue()}")
print(f"stderr: {captured_stderr.getvalue()}")
```

I would love to learn what I'm doing wrong. :-)

Comment: Maybe you can adapt this... https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the [wurlitzer library](https://pypi.org/project/wurlitzer/), which can do exactly that, i.e., capture the streams written to by a C library:

```py
import cv2
from wurlitzer import pipes

with pipes() as (out, err):
    cv2.VideoWriter("foo.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v"), 90000, (240, 240))

print(f"stderr: {err.read()}")
```

Comment: Cool - thanks for sharing!